# Overwriting state tree in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hey guys so I have a unique use case where I want to override the entire app state tree in redux from one of the reducers from combineReducer. Purpose being I want to be able to load a different session of the app (kinda like a save button).

However I don't know how to go about this, I can easily get the entire state from getState and store it but there doesn't seem to be one to set it. I've also tried looking into redux-persist but I'm not too sure how to pass the persister object to different component.

Any hints or clue? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Higher Order Reducer to replace whole the app's state.

[Higher Order Reducer](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ReusingReducerLogic.html)

Refer this link.

If you have any doubt on this ask that in comments.

```
const {combineReducers, createStore} = require('redux');

function todos(state=[], action){
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return [...state, action.data];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

var state = {
    todos: ['todo1']
}

var reducers = combineReducers({
    todos: todos
});

var store = createStore(HigherOrderReducer(reducers), state);

function HigherOrderReducer(reducers, initialState){
    let higherState = {
        state: initialState
    }
    return function(state = {}, action){
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'REPLACE_WHOLE_STATE':
                higherState.state = action.data;
                return higherState.state;
            default:
                return reducers(state, action);
        }
    }
}

store.subscribe(function(){
    console.log(store.getState());
})

store.dispatch({
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    data: 'todo2'
})

var newState = {
    todos: ['task1', 'task2']
}

store.dispatch({
    type: 'REPLACE_WHOLE_STATE',
    data: newState
})
```

Comment: Right now I am using combineReducer and each individual reducer control different part of the state. But not sure how to get reducer B to also change the state that reducer A is changing.

Comment: I just add example in my answer. If you have any dobuts on example ask in comments.

Comment: Yup, worked like a charm, had to change some stuff but that's to be expected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Question: why do you need the `higherState` variable for?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to replace the entire state in the reducer itself. So, instead of doing something like `object.assign({}, state, {...})` you would just `return newState`.

If what you are trying to do is to completely replace the state from the root-reducer level, you can write a conditional based on the combined states.

```
combineReducer(AReducer, BReducer, (CReducer.someCondition? CReducer : DReducer))
```

It's all just javascript. An alternative to all this is to use reduce-reducers to merge and generate a new state at whichever level you choose (root reducer or reducer).

Comment: Hmm, I'm not completely understanding how it'll all work. 
In my app, I have AReducer and BReducer correspond to different part of the app and from my understanding they control the state tree for those components. 
So would I have to use that ternary CReducer.someCondition on each state I want to change?

Comment: Yes. The idea of my example though is that you would use it to display either a CReducer or DReducer based on some state in CReducer. You can use the same general algo more than once but it might start getting clunky. I would recommend using combinereducers and reduce reducers to make it less clunky. Solutions like that will be depend heavily on your specific situation.